# Incrementing an integer every 150 rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to write a SELECT query that calculates a `BatchNumber` column that increments by 1 every 150 rows, starting at 1001.

The expected `BatchNumber` should be `1001` for the first 150 rows, then `1002` for rows 151-300, and so on...

I've tried using a division on a dynamic `ROW_NUMBER()`, but can't get it.

```
SELECT ID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT ID)) AS RowNumber
    ,CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(INT, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT ID)) % 150))=0
        THEN 0 ELSE 1001 END
    + CONVERT(INT,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT ID)) / 150))
    AS BatchNumber  
FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK);
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I can get it is:

```
SELECT ID
    ,1001
    + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT ID)) - 1) / 150
    AS BatchNumber
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, click the tickmark just under the Downvote button to mark the answer as Accepted :-)